# Storing geometry from a layer into a geopackage file with geotools plugin

Tags: geotools, geopackage

How can I store a geometry to a geopackage file?

```java
FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> fi = getLayer().getFeatureIterator((Envelope) null);
GeoPackage geopkg = new GeoPackage(...);
geopkg.init();

final FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> fc = new DefaultFeatureCollection(null, null);
 try {
    while (fi.hasNext()) {
        SimpleFeature sf = fi.next();
        Geometry geom = (Geometry) sf.getDefaultGeometry();
       ???
    }
} finally {
    fi.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't store just store a geometry in a geopackage. Like all GeoTools datastores you need to store features. The process is identical for all of them so take a look at the [shapefile tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html#write-the-feature-data-to-the-shapefile).